# Singleton and reuse of awaited coroutine

Tags: python, asynchronous, singleton, coroutine, pika

I have the following code:

```
class Singleton:
    __instance = None
    connection = None

    @staticmethod
    def getInstance(loop):
        if Singleton.__instance == None:
            Singleton(loop)
        return Singleton.__instance

    def __init__(self, loop):
        Singleton.__instance = self
        Singleton.connection = aio_pika.connect_robust(config.MQ_BROKER_URL, loop=loop)
```

for each incoming request I wait connection in a such way:

```
mq_connection = await Singleton.getInstance(asyncio.get_event_loop()).connection
```

And I get this error:

`RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine`

**Questions:**

- Probably I get some concept wrong here, but how can I get single connection within the same event loop?
- If singleton is a bad idea, how could I control the connections quantity to prevent creating connection for each request?